# How to correct breadcrumb path in orchard?

Tags: orchardcms, breadcrumbs

I have added menu widget as breadcrumb in orchard CMS. But when I open a blog post from home page the breadcrumb direction is home..How can I change the path that shows the correct direction? 
ex:Home->fruit->apple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve this problem by installing the Alias Breadcrumb link module